# Django + Queryset + m2m + ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to get a list with unique 'source' and all users added 'terms' for it, e.g.

from:

```
user1 s1 [t3,t4,t5]
user1 s2 [t1,t2]
user2 s1 [t1,t2]
user2 s2 [t3,t4,t5]
```

to:

```
s1 t1,t2,t3,t4,t5
s2 t1,t2,t3,t4,t5
```

my models:

```
class User_Filter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, null=True)
    terms = models.ManyToManyField(Term)

class Source(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('name', max_length=100, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField('url', unique=True)

class Term(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=100, unique=True)
```

I am playing around with this code:

```
sources = User_Filter.objects.values('source').distinct()
```

This line spits out dict with source ID:

```
{'source': 1}
{'source': 2}
```

And from this point I am stuck. Any help is really appreciated.

**Ugly solution:**

```
list = []
for s in User_Filter.objects.values('source').distinct():
    objs = User_Filter.objects.all().filter(source=s['source'])
    source = Source.objects.get(id=s['source']).url
    source_dict = {}
    terms = []
    for obj in objs:
        for term in obj.terms.all():
            if term.title not in terms: terms.append(term.title)
    source_dict['terms']=terms
    source_dict['url']=source
    to_scraper.append(source_dict)
print (list)
```

Comment: You should include the `Term` and `Source` models here as well

Comment: other models added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your data with this:

```
data = []

for source in Source.objects.all():
    terms = []

    for user in source.user_filter_set.all():
        terms.extend(user.terms.all().values_list('title', flat=True))

    data.append({'url': source.url, 'terms': list(set(terms))})
```

You iterate over each `Source` and get its related `User_Filter` instances. From there on, you get the `terms` for each `user` and add them to terms of the current `source`.

Then, you add to the `data` list, a representation of the `source` being processed. The `list(set(terms))` gets rid of possible duplicates in `terms`.

---

For an explanation of `user_filter_set`, please see the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) about the Many-to-one relationships.